# implementar metodo insertar_persona(...) y eliminar_persona(...)

Tags: java, base-de-datos

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class conexion {
    Connection co;  
    Statement stm;

    //jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]

    public static Connection iniciarConnection(){   
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            Connection co= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", "root", "");
            Statement stm = co.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Conectado correctamente a la Base de Datos");
            return co;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Clase no encontrada: "+e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion: "+e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error desconocido: "+e);
        }
            return null;
    }
}

 public void insertar_persona(String dni, String nombre, String apel1, String apel2, String pais, String ciudad) throws SQLException {

        // como hago para insertar los parametro de entrada a la tabla personas
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO personas "
            + "(dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, pais, ciudad"
            + "VALUES"
            + "(" + dni + "," + nombre + "," + apel1 + "," + apel2 + "," + pais + "," + ciudad + ")";

    try {
        dbConnection = iniciarConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        // execute insert SQL stetement
        statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }

            public void borrarPersona(String dni) {
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    //Usando consultas preparadas, más seguras y más rápidas
    String insertSQL = "DELETE "
            + "FROM personas"
            + "WHERE dni = ?";


    try {
         c = iniciarConnection();
        preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) iniciarConnection().prepareStatement(insertSQL);


        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}




}
```

El metodo insertar me funciona ya perfectamente,ahora estoy con el metodo borrar, a ver si me podeis echar una manita

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código que has intentado (para uno de los métodos) y explicar qué problema te has encontrado?

Comment: ¿Tu duda es sobre como definir los métodos o sobre como darles contenido?

Comment: mi duda es que no se como crear el metodo, lo intente de mil maneras pero no me da ningun error simplemente no me sale nada. Gracias

Comment: ¿Que significa no te sale nada? Sin el codigo de esos metodos no podemos indicarte el camino (la bola de cristal esta rota estos dias ;) )

Comment: ahi he puesto el metodo que quiero hacer, como interacciono con sql mediante consultas en java, esa es mi duda

Comment: Fijate que yo he puesto comilla simples en el sql y tu las has quitado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy fácil, usando consultas preparadas, como recomienda la [documentación de Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Las cuales permiten escribir un código más seguro con respecto a la Inyección SQL, y además funciona mucho más rápido.

Es una mala práctica enviar consultas **enteras** a la base de datos. Por eso verás que en la instrucción, los valores son reemplazados por signos de `?`, porque los mismos se pasarán separados de la instrucción misma, de esa manera se evita que un usuario mal intencionado envía consultas peligrosas a la BD.

Tu `Clase` se parecería a algo como esto:

```
public class DBManager {

//Poner datos de conexión propios 
private static final String DB_DRIVER = "";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "";
private static final String DB_USER = "";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "";

public void insertarPersona(String dni, String nombre, String apel1, String apel2, String pais, String ciudad)
{

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    //Usando consultas preparadas, más seguras y más rápidas

    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLA"
            + "(DNI, NOMBRE, APEL1, APEL2, PAIS, CIUDAD) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);

        //Pasar los valores en orden y según su tipo

        preparedStatement.setString(1, dni);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, nombre);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, apel1);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, apel2);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, pais);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, ciudad);

        //Ejecutar consulta 
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Registros insertados!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}


//Obtener conexión
private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}

}
```

Comment: se que la politica de los comentarios es no agradecer, pero me has ayudado mucho, a los demas tambien les agradezco, me habeis ayudado mucho, pero tu has sido el que mejor has sabido ajustarte al codigo

Comment: @Selito95 Si el problema ha sido resuelto, no olvides marcar como solución la respuesta que ha resuelto  el problema, o la que te ha mostrado con más claridad el camino. De ese modo la pregunta no aparece como _sin resolver_.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que lo tienes definido fuera de la clase. La forma correcta de hacerlo es así:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class conexion {
    Connection co;  
    Statement stm;

    //jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]

    public static Connection iniciarConnection(){   
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            Connection co= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", "root", "");
            Statement stm = co.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Conectado correctamente a la Base de Datos");
            return co;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Clase no encontrada: "+e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion: "+e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error desconocido: "+e);
        }
            return null;
    }

    public static void insertar_persona(String dni, String nombre, String apel1, String apel2, String pais, String ciudad){
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Otra recomendación. En lugar de pasar tantos parámetros a tu método es mejor que crees una clase Persona que tenga todas esas propiedades. El código va a quedar mucho más limpio y va a ser más fácil de interpretar y mantener.

Comment: Creo que no lo tiene fuera de la clase sino que cuando se le ha pedido el metodo, lo ha pegado al final sin darse cuenta de las llaves.

Comment: Podría ser. La verdad es que cuando lo he visto me extrañó que le compilase :)